# MVCCheckBoxList, Many rows of checkboxes, styling to line up properly

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVCCheckBoxList which is an extension for ASP.NET MVC that I downloaded and installed.  It works very nice, but I have a lot of check boxes and it carries over to multiple lines.  In some instances it is putting the check box on a different line than the corresponding label.  Another problem is that all of my check box labels are of different lengths.  The way I have it now is it just creates the check boxes across the screen and when it gets to the end of the line it just goes down to the next line.  I want to make it so the checkboxes line up in nice columns and the boxes are aligned.  Is there any way to do this?  The helper method allows you to specify a class that will get applied to each check box/label combo, but I am having problems getting the proper CSS.

Here is the code in the view:

```
<section>
<label>Select Activities</label>
<div id="activities">
    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds,
                              model => model.AvailableActivities,
                              activity => activity.ValidActivityID,
                              activity => activity.desc,
                              model => model.IsSelected,
                              Position.Horizontal,
                              x => new { @class = "actcheckbox" })
</div>
</section>
```

Here is my css so far:

```
  .actcheckbox {
display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<section>
<label>Select Activities</label>
<div id="activities">
    <input checked="checked" class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds511" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="1"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds511">Fishing</label> &nbsp;
    <input checked="checked" class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds512" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="2"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds512">Hunting</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds513" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="3"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds513">Boating</label> &nbsp; <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds514" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="4"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds514">Skiiing</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds515" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="5"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds515">Hiking</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds516" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="6"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds516">Biking</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds517" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="7"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds517">Swiming</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds518" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="8"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds518">Shopping</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds519" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="9"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds519">Surfing</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds520" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="10"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds520">Go Karts/ATV</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds521" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="11"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds521">Basketball</label> &nbsp; <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds522" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="12"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds522">Tennis</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds523" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="13"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds523">Tubing</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds524" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="14"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds524">Paintball</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds525" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="15"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds525">Ice Skating</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds526" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="16"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds526">Snow Mobiling</label> &nbsp;
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds527" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="17"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds527">Water Skiing</label> &nbsp; 
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds528" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="18"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds528">Scuba Diving</label> &nbsp; 
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds529" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="19"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds529">Shuffle Board</label> &nbsp; 
    <input class="actcheckbox" id="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds530" name="PostedActivities.ActivitiesIds" type="checkbox" value="20"></input>
    <label class="actcheckbox" for="PostedActivities_ActivitiesIds530">Horseback Riding</label> &nbsp; 
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML this helper generates

Comment: I edited the original question with the generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the biggest problem is that the input/label combos aren't wrapped together in `<span>` or `<div>` tags.  If you could do that, your css would be almost sufficient (JSFiddle example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7f85akc5/)).

However, since that might not be an option with your current html helper setup, the following is the best alternative I could come up with (though it does feel almost like a hack):

```
input.actcheckbox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 120px;
}

label.actcheckbox {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: -120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 0;
}
```

The basic idea of it is to give the label a width of 0 and make the checkbox take up the space of its label.  This lets the size of the checkbox determine when the checkbox and its label should wrap to the next line.

Note: This method requires that the width of the labels be fixed.  This may be undesirable, though in your case, since you want them to line up prettily, it's probably what you want.  This also works best if the `#activities` div has a fixed width, though that could cause cross-device compatibility issues.

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sxejn60v/)'s an example.  Hope this was useful.

Comment: this is almost perfect on mine.  For some reason, mine is doing a reverse indent on the first row.  So all of the rows are lining up perfectly besides the first.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or the code?  It might be fixable by just targeting the first checkbox (or label) by using `:nth-child(1)` and playing with its `left` and `margin-left` properties.

Comment: I got it.  Thanks.  I added "float:left" to each of the CSS rules that you gave me above and it fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to set proportionate widths so it will not wrap. Setting them up as inline is a good start.

```
#activities {
    width: 100%;
}

#activities input {
    width: 5%;
}

#activities label {
    width: 20%;
}
```

You may use the `:nth-child(ood)` and `:nth-child(even)` pseudo class. But, I'll let you figure it out.